# Cell values controlled by master/top level entry

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a user entry form in Excel (I know it isn't the ideal way, but it's the preferred program for all things here).

I have a series of questions that the user needs to answer that are broken into sub sets. I would like to have a master question for each subset that will auto assign all the remaining items to "no". I have each subset of questions in its own table to simplify other tasks (the Table is named "Process") and the top left cell is the master yes/no entry cell. The worksheet macro I have crashes Excel right after it runs. Am I missing something?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If [Process].Cells(1, 1).Value = "No" Then
        [Process].Cells(2, 1).Value = "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm guessing that the test runs continuously for the test and that causes the crash. But I'm not sure how to best exit the sub.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW I'm pretty sure this is a dupe... only I can't find it ATM.

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet_Change` handler executes whenever any cell value changes on that worksheet.

`[Process]` being a bracketed expression, it gets evaluated at run-time by Excel, which has no choice to assume you're referring to the active sheet (the one handling `Worksheet_Change`), which means your `Process` table is on the very sheet being modified.

Your handler is callling itself, *ad infinitum*, until the call stack violently explodes.

Disable worksheet events before:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And restore them after:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

That way any modifications you make to the worksheet while handling that "hey I'm being modified" event, won't fire up another "hey I'm being modified" event.

---

I'd suggest you also replace the bracketed expression by actual object model calls, so as to get compile-time validation.

```
Public Property Get ProcessTable() As ListObject
    Set ProcessTable = Me.ListObjects("Process")
End Property

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    Static table As ListObject
    If table Is Nothing Then Set table = ProcessTable

    With table.Range
        If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "No" Then .Cells(2, 1).Value = "No"
    End With

CleanExit:    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: I see how your code should work and it makes a lot more sense than the quick way I had attempted. However, nothing happens when I try to use your code. My table appears to be named correctly in both the table properties and in the VBA editor. I tried to replace the cell change with a msgbox to get a popup when it runs, but nothing happened so somehow I'm not entering the loop.

Comment: Sorry, loop was the wrong word. I was just trying to test to see if the macro was even firing. I do have worksheet events active. And I have the above sub's on the worksheet page that the table is on, that's the correct place?

Comment: The `Change` event will fire whenever anything *changes* on *that* worksheet, if worksheet/application events are enabled. Verify that you have the correct handler signature/name. At the top of the code pane, the left-hand dropdown should say "Worksheet", and the right-hand dropdown should say "Change". If that's not the case then you're not handling the `Change` event and nothing is calling your procedure.

Comment: I do in fact have both of those on Sheet7 where my table is.  perhaps a better question is, I have 7 of these sub tables. Is what we are attempting the best way to handle this "master" yes/no control that I want. Should I just be going about it differently than a VBA macro to do it?

Comment: I added in a message box above and below the Application.enableevents lineand it will active when I change the value of any cell. It seems that the With table.range part is what isn't working.

Comment: Your question was about one table on one specific worksheet. If you want to handle the case where anything changes on any sheet, handle `SheetChange` in the `ThisWorkbook` module; use the `Sh` parameter to determine which sheet was modified, and the `Target` parameter to determine which specific range/cell was modified. Learn to use the debugger: breakpoints (F9), step-through (F8), the immediate pane (Ctrl+G). Place a breakpoint on the `Set ProcessTable = Me.ListObjects("...")` instruction, hit F8 and then do `?ProcessTable Is Nothing` in the debug pane. Should say `False`. Fix accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

```
If [Process].Cells(1, 1).Value = "No" Then
   [Process].Cells(2, 1).Value = "No"
   End

End If
```